# Decidable equality for computable functions $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, lo.logic, computational-complexity, computability-theory

Suppose we have two computable functions $f, g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$. When is $f=g$ algorithmically decidable?

For example it is decidable if $f$ and $g$ are polynomials of a priori known degree.

Comment: If polynomials have degree at most $N$, it suffices to check equality at $N+1$ different points.

Comment: The question is not well-defined to me. If computable $f,g$ are given, they're equal or not equal, so well, there's no computability question. If the input is $f,g$, the question is in which way do you input them.

Comment: @YCor the input is the source code of the program computing them and the question is to identify a wide class of programs where equality is decidable

Comment: That "wide class of programs" can't be very wide. Let $f(n)=0$ if $2n+2$ is the sum of two primes and $f(n)=1$ otherwise. Let $g$ be identically $0$. Both $f$ and $g$ are computable by very simple programs, but $f=g$ is an unsolved problem.

Comment: By [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem) it's hard to tell much from computer source code, if by that you basically mean a description of a Turing machine.